# C# ADO - Performance difference between one single large SQL command and many separate commands?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have some C# code which inserts (or updates) single records into SQL SERVER table like so:

```
[Open Connection]
  [Set up parameters]
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
[Close Connection]
```

I am now tasked with adding bulk inserts to this code, so wondered if the following is sufficient:

```
[Open Connection]
  [Begin Transaction]
  [Set up parameters]
  command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
  [Set up parameters]
  command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
  [Set up parameters]
  command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
  [Set up parameters]
  command4.ExecuteNonQuery();
  .
  .
  Etc
  [Commit Transaction]
[Close Connection]
```

The alternative being multiple sql statements concatenated into a single SQL statement and run in one command, which could get very messy??

From a performance point, would it be sufficient to simply use the many command approach above or is it advisable to create the single sql statement.

The single statement approach is going to be very complicated, I'd like to weigh up the benefit (if any) for the effort required to implement.

Thanks

Comment: As usual, when someone asks this kind of question, my answer is to look at this: [Which Is Faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You can reuse an SqlCommand btw by calling clear on its params

Comment: The seperate commands above are just for the description of this post, the commands are held in a List<IDbCommand> and executed using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

In general, passing multiple statements into the database is going to take longer because of the overhead incurred in getting data and out of the database.  This can be ameliorated by using parameterized queries that don't need to be recompiled, but there is still overhead.

That said, your two approaches are *not* the same.  Individual inserts/updates will typically be committed at the end of the transaction.  So, when you do multiple such operations, each is committed before the next starts.  If you wrap them all into a single statement, then that is one transaction, and you will never have partial results.

I would argue that what you need to happen in the event of a failure should drive the consideration on whether you do this in one statement or multiple statements.  Do you want partial changes to the data?  Or do you want all of the changes to take effect, or none at all?  (You can also get this functionality by opening a transaction, but that is another matter.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, I plan on opening a transaction and rolling back if a failure occurs. I need an all or nothing approach.